# Solving $x^{x^{x^{x^...}}}=a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solving $$x^{x^{x^{x^...}}}=a$$
My attempt is
$$x^{x^{x^{x^...}}}\log(x)=\log (a)$$
$$a\log(x)=\log(a)$$
$$x=a^{1/a}$$
that means I can select any value of $a$ to get the root,but when I selected some values, I found them not satisfy the original equation, for example
$a=3$,$a=5$, and so on,

Is there a mistake in my procedures, 
thanks for any help

Comment: Somewhat close to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581868/an-infinitely-powered-expression-large-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-cdot

Comment: I think there are a dozen questions almost exactly like this already on the site.

Comment: Read about [infinite tetrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights). In particular, your left-had expression only has meaning for $x\in\left[e^{-e},e^{1/e}\right]\approx\left[0.065988\ldots,1.4476\right]$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is correct, at least for $x$ from $e^{-e}$ to $e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, by a proof by Euler. See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) page for a much more detailed explanation, and check out the Tetration Forum online for a ton of information (much will likely be above the average mathematician (myself included) as the field is somewhat specialized, but I've always enjoyed browsing the site!)

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is such that $x^{x^{x^{\cdot\,^{\cdot\,^\cdot}}}}$ has a limit $a$.  Then, $x^a=a$.

Comment: Are you saying that another approach shows that the OP's approach was correct? The point of this answer is not clear.

Comment: Yes, that is my point.